# QQuickView - resize the content without delay / lag

Tags: qt, qml

An image often being the easiest way to explain something, here is a little screengrab of the problem I'm having:

[image: laggy resize]

If you look at the right side of the window, you can see that the content is resized with a visible lag / delay. It's a problem that happens in quite a lot of applications, but I was wondering if there is a way to fix this in a Qt application using `QQuickView` and QML content.

Basically my application is created like this:

```
QQuickView view;
view.resize(400, 200);
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::ResizeMode::SizeRootObjectToView);
view.setSource(...);
```

The QML's content is just an item with 2 rectangles to highlight the problem.

**Edit**: here is a simplified version of the QML file (yes, the simplified version also suffers from the same problem ;p)

```
import QtQuick 2.12
Item {
    Rectangle {
        color: "black"
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 10 }
    }
}
```

**Edit2**: Running this small QML snippet through the `qmlscene` executable also shows the same delay / lag.

**Edit3**: The same problem occurs on some Linux distros but not on some others: on my Ubuntu it works fine, but on my CentOS 7 is shows the same delay / glitches as on Windows. Both Qt version were 5.12.3. On an old OSX it works fine (tested on Qt 5.9) I'm really lost now ^^

Is there any way to prevent this kind of delay ? The solution will probably be platform specific since it seems the problem comes from the fact that the native frame is resized before Qt has the possibility to get the event, and so the content gets resized with a 1 frame delay ... but I'd like to know if anyone has an idea on how to handle this ?

Any help or pointer appreciated :)

Regards,
Damien

Comment: show the .qml..

Comment: updated the main post with the QML.

Comment: In my case in Linux, Qt 5.12.3 with the QML that you have provided I do not observe what you indicate, you can provide the QML that you use in your image

Comment: Then it is either a platform specific bug (e.g. works on Linux, not on Windows) or you have a difference in the C++ part: as I wrote in the post, the simplified QML example I wrote **also exhibits the same lag as in the screengrab**

Comment: If it is something specific to an OS it is more likely that it is a bug, and SO is not the right place to look for solutions, it is advisable to report the bug to Qt

Comment: Actually I have experienced similar stuff on Debian 9, with Qt 5.11 (btw, didn't try this simplified example). So, I would say it's probably not that platform specific

Comment: I tested the sample also on my Ubuntu (Qt 5.12) and on an old OSX (Qt 5.9) On both resizing was perfect. I only get this behavior on Windows on this small example :/

Comment: This is part of the asynchronous nature of property binding in QML. This reminds me of an issue I've seen with moving a frameless `Window` around where I had to fetch the coords from c++ by calling `cursorPos()`, otherwise, the window will jump all over the place. You can follow the same logic and fetch the `window` dimensions from c++ and set them directly to your `Item`. Please post it here if you manage to do it. GL

Comment: Property binding and QML are (as far as I know) completely platform independant: If this was the problem, it should happen on all platforms instead of just Windows.
I tried playing a bit with overriding QQuickView's nativeEvent, and I noticed something weird: when resizing from the left, we receive a move and size native events in this order. But then the QQuickView's corresponding moveEvent and resizeEvent methods are called in the other way around (resize before move) But this is a bit too low level for my understanding so I stopped investigating this.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your update - content gets resized with a 1 frame delay.
And there is a quite simple hack to handle this.
Use nativeEventFilter, handle
WM_NCCALCSIZE with pMsg->wParam == TRUE and remove 1px from top or from bottom.

```
if( pMsg->message == WM_NCCALCSIZE and pMsg->wParam == TRUE )
{
    LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS szr = NULL;
    szr = reinterpret_cast<LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS>( pMsg->lParam );
    if( szr->rgrc[0].top != 0 )
    {
        szr->rgrc[0].top -= 1;
    }
}
```

Regards, Anton

Answer (score 0):

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
```

There is no obvious lag after I use OpenGL.

If so, try the following code：

```
if (msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE) {
   *result = WVR_REDRAW;
   return true;
}
```