# Resizing an application using Qt Creator is buggy and laggy

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-designer

So as the title says , I'm having trouble making my GUI stop being laggy, for example when I drag the left side of the GUI it stretch's in a weird way and has slow animation , also my cursor reaches the point before the GUI and it takes like half a second to reach the exact shape that is wanted.
this the case for the four 8 possible resizing options (left,right,bottom right etc ..) .

I'm using Qt Creator and writing in QML .
and I'm using this function to resize :

```
mainWindow.startSystemResize("some edge");
```

and the following flags are applied to the window application:

```
flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
```

**Edit**
So I made the following example code and it has the same kind of problem :

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 1000
    height: 580
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 500
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Test")

    //removing the windows default bar
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#2c313c"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            x: 205
            y: 133
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "#e03d3d"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
    //for resizing using the mouse
    property int bw: 5
    MouseArea {
        id: resizingWindow
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        cursorShape: {
            const p = Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY);
            const b = bw + 10; // Increase the corner size slightly
            if (p.x < b && p.y < b) return Qt.SizeFDiagCursor;
            if (p.x >= width - b && p.y >= height - b) return Qt.SizeFDiagCursor;
            if (p.x >= width - b && p.y < b) return Qt.SizeBDiagCursor;
            if (p.x < b && p.y >= height - b) return Qt.SizeBDiagCursor;
            if (p.x < b || p.x >= width - b) return Qt.SizeHorCursor;
            if (p.y < b || p.y >= height - b) return Qt.SizeVerCursor;
        }
        //        acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton // don't handle actual events
        DragHandler {
            id: resizeHandler
            //            grabPermissions: TapHandler.TakeOverForbidden
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: if (active) {
                                 const p = resizeHandler.centroid.position;
                                 const b = bw + 5; // Increase the corner size slightly
                                 let e = 0;
                                 if (p.x < b) { e |= Qt.LeftEdge }
                                 if (p.x >= width - b) { e |= Qt.RightEdge }
                                 if (p.y < b) { e |= Qt.TopEdge }
                                 if (p.y >= height - b) { e |= Qt.BottomEdge }
                                 mainWindow.startSystemResize(e);
                             }
        }
    }


}
```

PS:
In order to run this you need to put the code in Qt Creator and then run the QML code and try to resize in one the 8 directions

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I had the same issue recently and found this question, is that what you're talking about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923879/qquickview-resize-the-content-without-delay-lag I didn't find a solution; it might be a platform-specific bug, so you'll probably have to bear with it. Although one thing I noticed is that, weirdly, the performance gets better the more complex your application is (I can't think of an explanation, but at least that's what it seems to me).

Comment: @splaytreez yeah that's the same problem with me, 
The best solution is to build the application without the flag Qt.FramelessWindowHint .
But then I'll have the that sad default white top bar that windows 10 has instead of something I want to design .